# Reformat only the home partition

Tags: partitioning

I have 3 partitions: swap, / and /home. How can I safely reformat /home? Do I have to take additional steps aside from ordinary reformating?

Comment: Seems like an XY problem. It is not clear why you would want to do that. Presumably you have another problem, and you think it can be solved by reformatting. That is not necessarily the best solution. Reformatting your home without technical precautions will break your installation.

Comment: why would you need to format /home? If you want to get rid of a user, delete the user. If you want to reset a user delete anything in /home/$USER of $USER (home will be recreated  on the next login). I do not see any reason on why you would need to format /home and not /? I can understand formatting / and not /home but not the other way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you already create some backups of your important data (because they are hard to recover after a reformat).

The following step should do it:

- Login as root (required, since you will remove the home folder of the current user)

  ```
  $ sudo su –
  ```
- Unmount the /home folder

  ```
  $ umount /home
  ```
- Reformat the home partition (make sure, hat you select the right partition. Check in `/etc/fstab` and run `lsblk`)

  ```
  $ mkfs.ext4 -F /dev/sdXX
  ```
- Mount the empty filesystem to `/home` (if the filesystem has changed, modify `/etc/fstab` accordingly)

  ```
  $ mount /home
  ```
- Re-Create home folders for existing users.

  ```
  $ cp -r /etc/skel /home/username
  $ chown -R username:usergroup /home/username
  ```

That’s it.